# jqgrid / free-jqgrid and Material Design Icons (.mdi)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, icons, material-design, free-jqgrid

With jqgrid or free jqgrid, is possible use a iconSet: "Material Design" and use this kind of icons:?
https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/7.1.96/

I see in the code of JS file, references to: jQueryUI icons, fontAwesome icons and Glyph icons, but no references to Material Design icons.

Is possible modify this demo for Material design icons?
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4.htm

The icons would be like this, more or less (I suppose):

```
  $.jgrid.icons = {
     common: "mdi",
     page: "mdi mdi-page-previous",
     next: "mdi mdi-page-next",
     prev: "mdi mdi-page-previous",
     first: "mdi mdi-page-first",
     last: "mdi mdi-page-last",
     loading: "mdi mdi-loading mdi-spin",
     rowSelected: "mdi mdi-checkbox-marked",
     rowUnselected: "mdi mdi-checkbox-blank-outline",
     pager: {
       cap: "mdi mdi-view-grid-outline",
       page: "mdi mdi-numeric-1-to-9",
       pgFirst: "mdi mdi-page-first",
       pgPrev: "mdi mdi-page-previous",
       pgNext: "mdi mdi-page-next",
       pgLast: "mdi mdi-page-last"
     },
     actions: {
       edit: "mdi mdi-pencil",
       add: "mdi mdi-plus",
       save: "mdi mdi-content-save",
       cancel: "mdi mdi-window-close"
     }
   };
```

Thanks.